# Selenoid - Parallel Testing in Cucumber 4 in Maven using Junit

Tags: maven, selenium, junit, cucumber, selenoid

Well, I am able to launch my Cucumber features in parallel using Maven Surefire Plugin. I am also able to launch these tests remotely in containers using Selenoid as well.

However, when I launch my tests, they are only launched in Chrome as per my default configuration. I want to launch different tests in different browsers. Is there any dynamic way of doing it?

I did a bit of research and found that tagging each scenario with browser name like @chrome or @firefox. If I adopt the same methodology, my scenarios will always run in the same dedicated browsers.

Comment: As a core Selenoid developer I can confirm that this issue should be solved in the code. Selenoid launches everything requested from code.

Comment: @vania-pooh I agree with you totally. I had even thought of adding CucumberTags dynamically during the runtime. It's just I am not able to find more simplistic approach!

Comment: Unfortunately I have never used Cucumber, but I think this could be done with parameterized tests: https://webkul.com/blog/parametrization-in-cucumber/ Just use browser name and version as parameters.

Comment: @vania-pooh thanks for the link and keep up the good work with Selenoid.